# Resharper 7.1 error message "Invalid control type"

Tags: resharper, ajaxcontroltoolkit, resharper-7.1

I have this HTML code

```
<ajaxtoolkit:collapsiblepanelextender runat="server" id="cpePresentata"
targetcontrolid="panPresentata" expandcontrolid="imgHideShowPresentata"
collapsecontrolid="imgHideShowPresentata" imagecontrolid="imgHideShowPresentata"
collapsedtext="Mostra stato" expandedtext="Nascondi stato"
expandedimage="./Img/expand.jpg" collapsedimage="./Img/collapse.jpg"
suppresspostback="True" behaviorid="cpePresentata"/>
```

Width Resharper 6.1 no error was displayed.

I upgrade at Resharper 7.1 and **expandcontrolid**, **collapsecontrolid** and **imagecontrolid** are underlined in red. The Resharper message error is "Invalid control type".

Below the HTML code of image

```
<asp:panel runat="server" id="panHeaderPresentata">
  <div class="collapsePanelHeader">
    <img id="imgHideShowPresentata" src="./Img/expand.jpg" alt="Mostra stato"/>                                           
  </div>
</asp:panel>
```

I use Visual Studio 2010

Any ideas?

Thanks

Sara

Comment: It's possible Resharper 7.1 doesn't know about the AjaxControlToolkit.  Is it a build error or just a warning that you can ignore?

Comment: In effects the same error is with `<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender PopupDragHandleControlID`. It isn't a buid error. The web site run correctly, but Resharper reports it as an error.
Is annoying because in the HTML code I have several red error (in the page there are many `ModalPopupExtender` and `collapsiblepanelextender`)

Comment: Seems like a bug. Could you please report this at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com ? If possible, please attach a working page sample. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @DmitryOsinovskiy. As suggested I report this at [youtrack.jetbrains.com](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com)

Comment: This still appears to be an issue in Resharper Ultimate 2019.2 unfortunately as I'm seeing the exact same thing that Sara reported